# emacs cannot open load file make-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, bison, mode, bisonc++

I was searching for a bison mode for emacs. I found [one implementation](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/gnu/emacs-lisp/incoming/bison-mode.el) (rather old, as it turns out). I have copied it to my `.emacs` file, `(require 'font-lock)` and `(require 'cc-mode)` as suggested on the [emacs wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BisonMode). But, the `bison-mode.el` file has the following line `(require 'make-regexp)` which gives the error

> Cannot open load file: make-regexp

Has the name of the library changed or do I need to install something else to make the file work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google `"make-regexp.el"` (with the double-quotes). You will see that you can download that file separately.  Then put it in your `load-path`.

(I am not a Bison user --- just doing what seems reasonable to find the file you need.  But it might be that you already have that file somewhere on your disk.  So search your disk first for it.  Once you have it, ensure that its location is in your `load-path`.)

Comment: I searched for make-regexp.el file and downloaded it. It was not present in the disk. Now the bison file works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Google is your friend. ;-)